# React-native FCM: Can't access notification data when the app is in background or killed

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, react-native-fcm

Im am trying to make work react-native-fcm, with firebase cloud messaging and a react-native app.

I am focusing mainly in Android

```
react-native@0.48.0
react-native-fcm@10.0.2
OS: Android - Emulator - 7.0.2
```

When my app is in foreground, its working perfectly, I receive the data in this function

`FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {`

And I can handle everything

[image]

But when the app is in background, the notification is received, but when I tap the banner, the app goes foreground, the same function is triggered, but the notif object is different, and don't contains my data.

[image]

When the app is killed, also the notification is received, but when I tap the banner, the app starts, the 
`FCM.getInitialNotification()`
is triggered, and my notif object doen't also contain the data, the same behaviour than in background

[image]

I am testing the format of the messages using node-gcm library, of firebase web interface, but nothing works.

This is a sample of my message, but I have tryed tons of combinations:

```
let message = new gcm.Message({
    priority: 'high',
    content_available: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
    data: {
        key1: 'message1',
        key2: 'message2'
    },
    notification: {
        title: "Hello, World",
        icon: "ic_launcher",
        body: "This is a notification that will be displayed if your app is in the background."
    },
    custom_notification: {
        key1: 'message1',
        key2: 'message2'
    }

});
```

How should I proceed to send and receive data in those cases? Because is driving me crazy.

If you need more data, ask for it :)

Thanks!!

Comment: did u get any solution, I am also facing the same issue, If u get please add your answer here.

Comment: It was a problem related of using two intents inside the android code (I used the another one for splash screen):
At the moment that I leave the code with only one intent, it follows the good behaviour

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026676/showing-fcm-notification-message-in-json-format-when-app-is-killed-or-in-backgro


please check this once if u have any solution. I am not using any Splash activity in android part.

Answer (score 3):

in my case, i was missing the notification's data setup when building the notification on foreground notification event firebase.notifications().onNotification

```
new firebase.notifications.Notification()
      .setNotificationId(fcmNotification.data.notificacionId)
      .setTitle(fcmNotification.title)
      .setBody(fcmNotification.body)
      .setData(fcmNotification.data) // <- this little bastard
```

so, when tapping the notification `data` was undefined on `firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened` even when the json that comes in `firebase.notifications().onNotification` had data field filled

Answer (score 0):

Issue: I was getting remoteData from messaging().getInitialNotification() and messaging().setBackgroundHandler() also not register.
solution: @react-native-firebase, @react-native-firebase/messaging is conflict with @notifee i simplly remove notifee module and it's works for me..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).