# Showing fcm notification message in JSON format when app is killed or in background in react-native-fcm

Tags: react-native, react-native-fcm

I am using react-native-fcm library for android device. I am getting notification properly when my application is running, but when my application is in the background or killed then I am getting notification data in JSON format similarly in an image I shared here.

[image]

```
componentDidMount() {
        // iOS: show permission prompt for the first call. later just check permission in user settings
        // Android: check permission in user settings
        FCM.requestPermissions().then(()=>console.log('granted')).catch(()=>console.log('notification permission rejected'));
        /*FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
            console.log('Token',token)
            // store fcm token in your server
        });*/
        this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async(notif) => {
            console.log('FCM notification', notif)
            this.sendRemote(notif)
        });

        // initial notification contains the notification that launchs the app. If user launchs app by clicking banner, the banner notification info will be here rather than through FCM.on event
        // sometimes Android kills activity when app goes to background, and when resume it broadcasts notification before JS is run. You can use FCM.getInitialNotification() to capture those missed events.
        // initial notification will be triggered all the time even when open app by icon so send some action identifier when you send notification
        /*FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notif => {
            console.log('FCM', notif)
            this.sendRemote(notif)
            //console.log('Initial Notification',notif)
        });*/

        FCM.getInitialNotification().then((notif: any) => {
            // for android/ios app killed state
            console.log("ifAny",notif)
            if (notif) {
                console.log("Any",notif)
                // there are two parts of notif. notif.notification contains the notification payload, notif.data contains data payload
            }
        });
    }




sendRemote(notif) {
    var data = notif.fcm.body;
    var title = notif.fcm.title;
    FCM.presentLocalNotification({
        title: 'App Name',
        body: title,
        big_text: title,
        large_icon: 'ic_launcher',
        priority: 'high',
        sound: "default",
        click_action: this.clickActions(notif),
        show_in_foreground: true,
        wake_screen: true,
        local: true,
        param: notif.notify_about,
        paramData: data
    });
}
```

**notify_about:'',
fcm:{action:null,
body:"{data:'',time:''}",
color:null,
icon: '',
tag:null,
title:"Notification title"}**

this is my data format which I am sending from the server.

Here I want to show only data body. But when the app is killed or in the background, it shows the complete body in the notification.And Its working fine when the app is running.

Comment: Can you add the format of the notification you sent ?

Comment: I added the format of notification, here some more data is coming like 'google.sent_time' which is default coming from firebase which I didn't include here.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't worked for me, anyway I change the way I am sending data from the server, now in the body part, I am sending my message and with a tag, I am sending my JSON data and now notification is coming fine.